# Git local master branch displays differently to live version, even though it's up-to-date

Tags: django, git, github, version-control

I have been working on one of the pages of my Django project on my local Git branch, and am now looking to merge those changes with my master branch.

I have checked out my local master branch, and viewed the page locally in the browser, however, what is being displayed by my local master branch is different to what is being displayed on the live version of the project.

When I view this particular page on the live version, it displays a PDF embedded in a 'tabbed content' area within the webpage, and on one of the tabs, the PDF shows a table with four columns.

However, when I view this page on my local master branch, the same tab shows a PDF displaying a table with only two columns... (choosing which columns to display on the PDF was the thing that I was most recently working on).

I have tried running a `git pull origin master` from my local master branch, to make sure that my local version is the same as/ up-to-date with the version on the live server, and Git displays a message stating that it is

> Already up-to-date

But if this is the case, then why am I not seeing all of the same columns displayed in the PDF table on my local version as I am in the live version?

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I am wrong, but I am assuming that when you say "live version", you are talking about the project on a server.

Once your merged your changes onto the local master branch from your local git branch (i.e `git merge your_local_random_git_branch`), these changes need to be pushed to your server not the other way around.

The reason why it shows

> Already up to date.

after doing `git pull origin master`, is because the remote repository is behind the local master branch so there is nothing to change on the local master branch. What you want to do is to push your changes from the local master branch like this:

```
git push origin master
```

Comment: Yes, the 'live version' is the version on the server. I am aware that `push` is what I want to use to push the changes from my local version to the version on the server, but as I mentioned in my OP, those changes are currently on another `branch`, (not master). I have committed the changes on 'myBranch' to my Git repository, and then checked out my local 'master' branch, ready to merge the changes from 'myBranch' into local 'master' before pushing. However, when I view the page I've been working on in my local 'master' it's not displaying the same as that page is when I view it on live...

Comment: That's what my issue is here... I don't want to merge the changes from 'myBranch' into my local 'master', before I'm sure that my local 'master' is up-to-date with the live 'master', in case after doing so, there are some other changes made that I was unaware of, which are overwritten, due to my local 'master' not being the same as the live 'master'... However, as mentioned in my OP, when I run a `git pull origin master` on my local 'master' branch (to make sure the code is up-to-date), I get a message telling me that it's already up-to-date, even though when I view the same page on live & my

Comment: can you do `git diff master origin/master` and tell me if you get any output?

Comment: No, this hasn't given me any output... It just went to another prompt: `user:folder$`

Comment: I assume I was meant to run the `diff` on my master branch?

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is from git then try:

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

This will make sure your remote is the exact same as origin.
If your code is fine then restart your local server and/or empty your browser cache.

Answer (score 0):

First please check if local master branch is accordant with origin/master, use `git checkout master` and `git log origin/master..HEAD`

1. If there has output, so you should reset local master to origin/master, just as Saksow said `git reset --hard origin/master`.
2. If there is no output, that means, there is no issue for git doing version control, you need to check Django, maybe caused by some settings or something (since I’m not familiar with Django)